# Form submit is not working for dropdown change in wordpress admin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, admin

I was working on submitting the form after change in dropdown in wordpress admin. I tried adding javascript to dropdown like `<select onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>`, this also didn't work for me. Even i tried using JQuery but didn't work.

**functions.php**

```
//**************function to add the javascript
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
    'dropdown', scripts and de-register, etc.
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dropdown.js', 
    array('jquery'),'20120206' 
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

//**************function to create the form
function Reviews_settings_page()
{ 
?>
  <div class="wrap">        
    <form method="POST" name="review_edit" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=Reviews-panel';?>">
       <?php
          settings_fields("section");
          do_settings_sections("Reviews-options");
          submit_button(); 
       ?>   
    </form>
  </div>
<?php
}

//*********function to create the dropdown
function display_Reviews_Brand_listing()
{
echo "<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown'>
    <option value=''>--select--</option>
    <option value='101'>EVEREST</option>
    <option value='102'>REVOLT</option>
    <option value='103'>HAWANA</option>
    <option value='104'>ELIZE</option>
</select>";
}

//**************adding functionality to wordpress admin
function display_Reviews_panel_fields()
{
add_settings_section("section", "Reviews", null, "Reviews-options");
add_settings_field("Reviews_url", "Select the Brand for Review", "display_Reviews_Brand_listing", "Reviews-options", "section");

register_setting("section", "Reviews_url");
}
add_action("admin_init", "display_Reviews_panel_fields");
```

**dropdown.js**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').click();
  });
} );
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks for your time and efforts for this problem.

Comment: Please post `submit_button();` or better a [mcve] showing the actual HTML

Comment: @mplungjan  submit_button() is will automatically add the submit button in wordpress

Comment: I only have your word for that ;)

Comment: @mplungjan His word and wordpress's too https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button

Comment: Sure, but HTML is better than some template when it comes to debugging jQuery

Comment: A fast check on the documentation provides you with your HTML for a function call without parameters: `<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes"  /></p>`

Comment: If it did not have the event-stealing id/name="submit" then $form.submit() or $form[0].submit() would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to clone your error. Keep the form action empty instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. your `dropdown.js` is added successfully by `add_action()`

for me also `onchange='this.form.submit();'` didn't work.

I tried different snippets to submit the form and finally below javascript worked for me

**dropdown.js**

```
function myFunction() {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
    }
```

**functions.php**

```
//update your form tag
<form method="POST" name="review_edit" id="review_edit" action="">

//update your <select>
<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown' onchange='myFunction();'>
```

Hope this will help you.